# How do you securely delete android 6 phone?

Tags: security, factory-reset

Settings states that phone data is encrypted already, so do I just do a factory reset and that's it? Is this the same as a hard reset?

Comment: Well factory reset means overwritng your current settings with factory settings.Yes thats the most secure way.

Comment: No it's not always the case, see here: https://press.avast.com/selling-your-smartphone-could-mean-selling-your-identity-avast-finds-used-smartphones-still-contain-personal-information-and-data

Comment: Factory resetting an encrypted device makes it essentially impossible to recovery any user data. As far as the SD card goes, just remove it and either keep it yourself, or physically damage the card and throw it away. Remember that you should delete your Google account from the device prior to performing a factory reset, or you (or the person you are selling the device to) will need to deal with FRP on the next startup.

Comment: Understood. Just wanted to make sure i got the steps right, as I've never done it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a factory reset of an encrypted device will wipe your device and delete the encryption key; it's a secure wipe (you can see some of the requirements [here](https://source.android.com/security/overview/implement)).  If your SD card is not encrypted you might need to handle that separately — a full (non-quick) zeroing format from a PC should be sufficient if you don't want to reuse or destroy it.

A "hard reset" can either refer to a hard power off and reboot, or to a factory reset; obviously in this context it would be the latter.

Comment: What should i be looking for in that link? Thanks for the answer.